# How to stream character from azure Http function

Tags: python, azure, function

I am able to get the respnce from an azure function as bytes and numbers but not able to stream the string data reversely into a different API.

How can I reverse the exact data of charectors using python.

I have used a generator to call the API stream data back and keep streaming functionality.

This is the generator meathod.

```
def main(get):
    stream = req.get_json()
    
    def generate():
        for pk in ["clark", "kinto", "isabel", "christo", "michel", "henry"]:
            yield pk

    return func.HttpResponse(generate())
```

**.json file:**

```
{
"scriptFile": "__init__.py",
"bindings": [
{
"authLevel": "anonymous",
"type": "httpTrigger",
"direction": "in",
"name": "req",
"methods": [  
"get"
]
},
{
"type": "http",
"direction": "out",
"name": "$return"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a function app in vscode using python and create an azure http function.

[image]

And now use following command for using azure function and importing it.

```
pip install azure-functions
```

Then, By using below code by referring [msdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-with-azure-functions#create-a-stream-analytics-job).

```
import  logging

from  django.http  import  StreamingHttpResponse

import  azure.functions  as  func

pk=["clark", "kinto", "isabel", "christo", "michel", "henry"]

def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

logging.info('Request has been passed to Http trigger')

def  stream_response():

for  ch  in  range(len(pk)-1,-1,-1):

yield  str(pk[ch]).encode('utf-8')

output = StreamingHttpResponse(stream_response(), content_type='text/plain')

output['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="charector.txt"'

return  func.HttpResponse(b'\n'.join(output.streaming_content), status_code=output.status_code, headers=output.headers)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq8Y4.png)
```

performed the above code in vscode and got the following output.

[image]

Now click on the link so we will get a pop-up to download as below.

[image]